# Command hotkeys and TextBox input in MVVM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, command, hotkeys

I have an application using MVVM pattern. There are some commands implemented using CommandReference and DelegateCommand classes. Thay are binded in the MainWindow InputBindings to some hotkeys. For example:
    KeyBinding Key="W" Command="{StaticResource WireframeCommandReference}"

And then I have a Properties window which displays some object's properties. Some of those properties are of type 'string' and they are edited shown in TextBox. And here I got a problem. When I try to type 'w' in the TextBox, nothing is typed but the command WireframeCommand is fired. 
What I want, is to be able to edit a property without firing any commands if a TextBox is active, else to fire a command. Any help?

Comment: Go with a chord (i.e., ctrl-w) or place the bindings below the level of the visual tree where the properties window is defined, closer to where you want this W command binding to be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot. The decision was to move the commands from MainViewModel to corresponding VMs. In case of wireframe, I moved it into ViewportVM and all works as it should. My problem was that the MainViewModel was used as a global storage for all commands.